# ggplot2 geom_ribbon with a different dataset is not working

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am creating a ggplot with the main data and I want to add a geom_ribbon from a different dataset, I thought this would be similar to adding a geom_line for instance but I am hitting a dead end...

Here is a reproducible example using data from the geom_ribbon help:

```
huron <- data.frame(year = 1875:1972, level = as.vector(LakeHuron))
huron2 <- data.frame(year = 1875:1972, min_level = as.vector(LakeHuron)-10,max_level = as.vector(LakeHuron)+10)
# This works fine
ggplot(huron,aes(x=year,y=level))+
  geom_line()+
  geom_line(data=huron2,aes(x=year,y=min_level),colour="lightblue")

# But this throws an error (Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'level' not found)
ggplot(huron,aes(x=year,y=level))+
  geom_line()+
  geom_ribbon(data=huron2,aes(x=year,ymin=min_level,ymax=max_level),colour="lightblue",alpha=0.5)
```

Am I missing something obvious here?

Comment: Hi nclaidiere. I did not check your example, but I think you will need a `inherit.aes = FALSE` in your `geom_ribbon` call. What's happening now, is that the `geom_ribbon` inherits the aesthetics of the initial `ggplot` object. That object has `y=level` specified, but your new data `huron2` does not have the column `level`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can adjust your code to get the desired output:

```
ggplot()+
  geom_line(data = huron, aes(x=year,y=level))+
  geom_ribbon(data = huron2, aes(x = year, ymin = min_level, ymax = max_level), fill = "lightblue", alpha = 0.5)
```

[image]

Note you originally had `colour = "lightblue"` which will only change the lines, so (assuming you want the range to be colored, not grey) I changed it to `fill = "lightblue"`

Comment: Thanks! That does the trick. Any idea if there is a reason for why it's behaving like that? or is it just a bug?

Comment: Not 100% sure, but whenever I use multiple datasets for something like this I tend to specify it for each `geom` instead of put it in the broader `ggplot()` - I've had this issue a couple of times. Glad it worked!